# Writing trigger using sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In Sql server, i write a trigger for update, actually i saw a sample trigger and i write my won triggr by using that. I have doubt in that trigger. My trigger goes like this:

```
 Create TRIGGER StudentScoresAfterUpdate
  ON StudentScores
 AFTER UPDATE
 AS
  IF ( UPDATE (Name) OR UPDATE (Score) )
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO StudentScoresHist (Name, Score, HistoryDate)
     select Name, Score, getdate()
      from deleted ;
    END;
```

In the above trigger why author write the if condition `IF ( UPDATE (Name) OR UPDATE (Score) )` can i write without  if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why author write the if condition `IF ( UPDATE (Name) OR UPDATE (Score) )` can i write without if condition?

An update trigger will fire when any update takes place in a table. In the case of a table with a large number of columns, you may only be interested in parts of your trigger running if *particular* columns were subject to update. That's what the `UPDATE` function lets you determine.

Can you write without the condition? Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [trigger function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which admittedly is not obvious from the documentation (it doesn't appear to be linked from [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).